# PHP/Javascript project keeps calling your-meme-site.com

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a localhost project that keeps sending requests to your-mime-site.com.

I have included these jquery plugins:

1. jQuery
2. jQuery.form
3. jQuery.validate
4. jQuery.ui

Everything else I have coded myself.

I have tried to use NetBeans to search the project for the string "your-meme-site" but it says that some lines are too long to be searched.

Does anybody know why or how this is happening?

Comment: Is it "mime" or "meme"? Also, how are you looking for these requests?

Comment: yes sorry it is your-meme-site

Comment: hm.... the *"too long lines"* reminds me on the nice **`p.a.c.k.e.r`** lines :\

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is your PC / network has been infected by virus that alter the DNS entry such that request to any arbitrary site gets redirected to your-mime-site.com

On Windows DNS host file exists on C:\windows\system32\etc\hosts. On UNIX it's on /etc/hosts. Ensure you don't have your-mime-site.com entry there.

Comment: It won’t show as going to `your-mime-site.com`, though, even with a `hosts` entry.

Comment: Try this - open a command prompt (Windows->Run->"cmd") and type `ping google.com`. IF the request goes to your-mime-site.com, you have a system-wide issue. At that point, you might want to check your nameserver configuration (`ipconfig -all`) or the host file.

Comment: ping is giving me "Pinging google.com [173.194.37.96]" So that looks good.

Comment: the only entry in hosts is 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: According to Firebug it sends a request there when I load stackoverflow also, so it looks like this computer has some sort of infection.

Comment: @guyfromfl: Do you have some odd plugins running in your browser?

Comment: I have installed Firebug and Avast was installed on this computer by someone else who works here, it added a website rating plugin which is what I am wondering if is the deal, however in the JS that is returned from the site it has some video link that appears to be a porn video..

Comment: ifra.innerHTML = '<iframe id="change" width="500" src="http://videosinnow.com/girl/unlocked.php" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe> <div id="esok"></div>';

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the "Initiator" column in the "Network" tab of Chrome's inspector to find what's triggering it.

Comment: I was using firebug. It seems to be tied to some google analytics. I do have a google calendar included in another part of the project, but there is no call to it in what I am working on.  The problem is I am developing some ajax calls right now and it is taking about 20 seconds per page load and throwing off my ajax testing.

Comment: It does not seem to be sending anything to your-meme-site.com in chrome.

Comment: @guyfromfl: Try to run your FireFox with all plugins disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled Garmin Communicator Plugin, BitCommet Video Player, Youtube Video Replay, and Java Console, the request went away.

I did reenable the Avast plugin and it is not the culprit, for anybody else who might get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  It was an extension in Firefox.  I started firefox in safe mode and the problem was gone.  Then disabled plugins and extensions one at a time till I found out it was a download flash video extension I had installed. Uninstalled the extension and it is gone.